# Function operating on each type of a variadic template typelist

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I have defined a typelist like this:

```
template <typename ... Types> struct typelist {};

using my_list = typelist<int, double, bool, float>;
```

Now I have a function template, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
void foo() {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}
```

and want to call this for every type in the typelist:

```
foo<int>();
foo<double>();
foo<bool>();
foo<float>();
```

I tried to find a recursive way to solve this, but I am having trouble to define the correct, probably nested, variadic templates for the required foo functions. Do you have any hints for a neat solution to this problem?

Comment: `typeid` is an operator, there is no `std::typeid`

Comment: Thanks, I just realized it and corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
template<class... Types> auto foo_foreach(typelist<Types...>) {
     return (foo<Types>(), ...);
}

int main() {
    foo_foreach(my_list{});
}
```

For a real oldschool, well, use template recursion you've attempted before:

```cpp
void foo_foreach(typelist<>) {}

template<class Head, class... Tail> void foo_foreach(typelist<Head, Tail...>);

template<class Head, class... Tail> void foo_foreach(typelist<Head, Tail...>) {
    foo<Head>();
    foo_foreach(typelist<Tail...>{});
}
```

Comment: Yes, needs some adjustments for older revisions.

Comment: Like this one, for instance.

Comment: @datasailor sorry, missed the revision tag in your post initially.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I like the c++17 version but have to stick to c++14 for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **c++20** answer only that uses lambda template.

```
template <typename... Ts, typename C>
constexpr void for_types(C&& c) {
    (c.template operator()<Ts>(), ...);
}

for_types<int, float, char>([]<typename T>()
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to work with C++14 then you can use the `initializer_list` trick to avoid a C++17 fold expression. This will hopefully be cheaper to compile than a recursive approach:

```cpp
template<class... Ts> void foo_foreach(typelist<Ts...>) {
    (void) std::initializer_list<int>{(foo<Ts>(), 0)...};
}

int main() {
    foo_foreach(my_list{});
}
```

Godbolt example: https://godbolt.org/z/o91Th466s

There is a good explanation of the `initializer_list` trick at https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/exploding-tuples-fold-expressions/

From that article:

> [...] parameter packs can only be expanded in contexts which expect a syntactic list, such as initializers and function call arguments. You can’t just expand them bare in a function body. In C++17, this problem has a nice solution, but prior to that we need to use some pretty horrible hacks. [...] one possibility [...] uses `std::initializer_list` to create a context in which the parameter pack can be expanded.
>
> The trick is the `, 0` inside the `initializer_list` initializer, which evaluates the function call, and uses 0 as the initializer value.